# Is there a way to check the version of a file?

Tags: c#, version

Is there a way to check the version of a file? I am using windows form application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use System.Diagnostics.[FileVersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx).GetVersionInfo(String)

FileVersionInfo

> Provides version information for a physical file on disk.

GetVersionInfo()

> Returns a FileVersionInfo representing the version information associated with the specified file.

```
var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).FileVersion;
```

Comment: Yes added an example.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
    var filePath = @"C:\Windows\System32\xwizard.exe";
    var fileInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath);
    var vers = fileInfo.FileVersion;
```